# Can not connect to mongodb replica set, deployed using docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, devops, replicaset

I am trying to setup MongoDB replica set deployment with docker-compose. It seems, something is missing in the network configuration and at the current moment I am getting ENOTFOUND or ECONNREFUSED error (see the description below).

Steps to reproduce

1. Create docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mongo1:
    hostname: mongo1
    image: mongo
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 30001:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint:
      [
        "/usr/bin/mongod",
        "--bind_ip_all",
        "--replSet",
        "rs0",
        "--dbpath",
        "/data/db",
      ]
    volumes:
      - ./my-volume/mongo/data1/db:/data/db
      - ./my-volume/mongo/data1/configdb:/data/configdb
  mongo2:
    hostname: mongo2
    image: mongo
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 30002:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint:
      [
        "/usr/bin/mongod",
        "--bind_ip_all",
        "--replSet",
        "rs0",
        "--dbpath",
        "/data/db",
      ]
    volumes:
      - ./my-volume/mongo/data2/db:/data/db
      - ./my-volume/mongo/data2/configdb:/data/configdb
  mongo3:
    hostname: mongo3
    image: mongo
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - 30003:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint:
      [
        "/usr/bin/mongod",
        "--bind_ip_all",
        "--replSet",
        "rs0",
        "--dbpath",
        "/data/db",
      ]
    volumes:
      - ./my-volume/mongo/data3/db:/data/db
      - ./my-volume/mongo/data3/configdb:/data/configdb

  mongo-setup:
    image: mongo
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
      - mongo2
      - mongo3
    command: >
      mongosh --host mongo1:27017 --eval
      '
      config = {
      "_id" : "rs0",
      "members" : [
        {
          "_id" : 0,
          "host" : "mongo1:27017"
        },
        {
          "_id" : 1,
          "host" : "mongo2:27017"
        },
        {
          "_id" : 2,
          "host" : "mongo3:27017"
        }
      ]
      };
      rs.initiate(config);
      '
```

2. Run `docker-compose up` (you should see multiple attempts (and restarts) of mongo-setup service trying to initialize replica set. Withing a minute it should do its job and replica set will be successfully configured)
3. Check that replica set is indeed initialized by running:

3.1. `docker ps` will output running docker containers:

```
0d254f165665   mongo     K   N   M  0.0.0.0:30002->27017/tcp   mongo_mongo2_1
ca1a6bbcd7fc   mongo     K   N   M  0.0.0.0:30001->27017/tcp   mongo_mongo1_1
c6a31065a78b   mongo     K   N   M  0.0.0.0:30003->27017/tcp   mongo_mongo3_1
```

3.2. `docker exec -it mongo_mongo1_1 mongosh` - enter one of the mongo containers

3.3. `rs.status().members.map(m => m.stateStr)` - check if primary is elected

4. Connect to your replica set with `mongosh` tool:

```
./mongosh mongodb://mongo1:30001,mongo2:30003,mongo3:30003/test2?replicaSet=rs0
```

At step 4. I am getting an error:

> Current Mongosh Log ID:   655cb0f059e685898230d913
> Connecting to:        mongodb://mongo1:30001,mongo2:30003,mongo3:30003/test2?replicaSet=adscan-mongo-set&appName=mongosh+2.0.2
> MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo2

Note: I also tried to add to /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 mongo1
127.0.0.1 mongo2
127.0.0.1 mongo3
```

It did not help. I just getting another kind of error:

> Current Mongosh Log ID:   655cb1d3aaedcb5ff1f652f3
> Connecting to:        mongodb://mongo1:30001,mongo2:30003,mongo3:30003/test2?replicaSet=adscan-mongo-set&appName=mongosh+2.0.2
> MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tried connection with Mongo Compass and mongosh tool. Same result.

Comment: Are you sure your replica sets are even coming _up_? You've mapped the same local-volume for all the instances `./my-volume/mongo/data1/db:/data/db` (3 times) so I would expect a lock file to allow only 1 instance to actually come up correctly and block the other two.

Comment: @aneroid, oh, my bad. I have changed volume path a bit as it contained project name. Each service in the docker compose have its own volume. I have checked - three separate folders are created and ech one is filled with some mongodb-related data (replication logs maybe). I have edited volume paths so they looked like in real project.

Comment: Why do you deploy a 3-member replica-set on a single host? Replication is used to keep the service available when one (or several) nodes are not available. When they run all on the same physical host, then this does not make much sense - unless you want to simulate and test a multi-host environment.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, good point! For now I want to scale read operations. The other additional data-bearing nodes will be located on other machines.